# How fast can a Twilight vampire heal from a gunshot?

Tags: vampire, twilight

Like, if a vampire was shot by a .50 caliber sniper rifle or an assault rifle. How fast would it take them to heal? Instantly? A few seconds/minutes?

How about if a vampire was repeatedly shot by a machine gun? Would they be able to survive that many continuous shots?

Comment: It quite possibly also depends on what sort of bullet it is. Vampires in Underworld are susceptible to UV rounds, which are bullets that contain some sort of glowing liquid. Regular bullets don't hurt them as much.

Comment: Correction. A regular bullet couldn't make a dent in them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### They wouldn’t need to

In Twilight, vampires have diamond-hard skin. Very few things can damage a vampire,  short of another vampire, a shapeshifter, or perhaps a werewolf. Bullets would just bounce off.

> "Then, suddenly, Riley was there, between me and them. I remember
> thinking he was the whitest guy I’d ever seen. He didn’t even look at
> the others when they shot him. Like the bullets were flies. You know
> what he said to me? He said, ‘Want a new life, kid?’”
>
> —*The Short Second Life of Bree Tanner*

Further,

> But I could also see Raoul, Kevin, and the rest, sparkling disco-ball
> monsters in the center of a busy downtown street, the bodies piling
> up, the screaming, the helicopters whirring, the soft, helpless cops
> **with their dinky little bullets that wouldn’t make a dent,** the
> cameras, the panic that would spread so fast as the pictures bounced
> swiftly around the globe.
>
> —*The Short Second Life of Bree Tanner*

It probably would not matter whether they were shot with a machine gun, a rifle, or any other kind of standard gun. The force simply wouldn't be enough to penetrate their skin. One would need a purpose-built weapon to have any chance.

Comment: (Trivia) Apparently, there's a difference between a stone's hardness and its "toughness". Diamonds are considered hard because they are hard to scratch, but they're not as tough as jades which are softer. On the Mohs scale of mineral hardness, it means the jade can be scratched more easily than the diamond. But jades were preferred for making weapons, because they are tougher and don't break as easily, even if they scratch. Example: you can scratch leather shoes with your nails, but they don't break when dropped. You cannot scratch a glass with your nail, but they break if you drop them.

Comment: Of course it doesn't change anything to the answer which is still valid for the question being asked. I guess it only means whoever wrote Twilight didn't know the difference between a mineral's hardness and its toughness.

Answer (score 1):

While Twilight vampires are extremely hardy, they are not invulnerable.

One of the justifications for their "humans must not know we are real" rule is that weapon development was reaching a point where they could be a threat.

While an easy interpretation for this would be missiles and nukes, it should be taken into account that this rule is a few hundred years old.  You can interpret from this that while "all gunpowder weapons" are not a threat (see quote in Adamant's answer), sufficiently powerful ones may be considered a threat.  Perhaps in the beginning it was just cannon and explosives, but with more powerful, efficient, and precise firearms, the larger handheld weapons (such as the .50 caliber mentioned in the question) would be a threat.

In the vampire vs vampire fights in the novels, most damage is done by physical force delivered by some form of martial arts.  I think there was some mention of biting, but it was primarily brute force.   Losers were dismembered and burned, which could point to flamethrower weapons also being a threat.

The activity of burning a vampire after dismemberment would seem to show that reattachment would be possible.  So the physical trauma is to subdue the opponent with the fire to finish the job.

The speed at which the burning is performed would point to a rapid recovery time.

Answer (score -3):

### They wouldn't.

A .50 cal round would punch through their bodies and possibly sever limbs. The people who say the bullets bounce off of them don't have an effen clue what they're talking about. If a large diamond existed and I shot with my .50 cal (because I have one), the diamond would shatter. Mainly because diamonds don't have the ability to absorb impact. In a word, diamonds are BRITTLE.

**Jewelers cut diamonds into shape.** Does this mean that jewelers have werewolf teeth to cut the diamonds with? NO. Jewelers have been cutting diamonds since 1375. Today, jewelers use lasers to cut diamonds because of the precise cut that is made by a laser.

So, a powerful laser would cut a sparkly twipire in half. Can a vampire outrun a laser? I dunno, can a vampire move at the speed of light?

Comment: One suspects that "diamond-hard" is a metaphor, and that specific quotes about the vulnerability of vampires to bullets are more useful.

Comment: For the records, a Prince Rupert's drop (made of molten glass) can withstand a 7.62 mm round shot from an AK-47. And it's "just glass".

Answer (score -3):

"Diamond-hard" means hard like diamonds.  Diamonds can be shattered, even with bullets.

"Well, that wouldn't work on a vampire."  Well.... that means they are STRONGER than diamonds and not "diamond-hard" at all.

If I say a material is as strong as steel, but can be broken at all, THEN IT'S NOT STRONG AS STEEL - IT'S WAY WAY WAY WAY STRONGER THAN STEEL. Mainly because steel can be broken.

Comment: The fact that they can be shattered is a function of their brittleness, which is [distinct from hardness](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-hardness-and-brittleness). Carbon nanotubes are a substance that is similar in hardness to diamond, but much less brittle--see [this article](http://www.nanowerk.com/spotlight/spotid=17548.php) which mentions that "Carbon nanotubes, due to their unique combination of high elastic modulus and high strain to failure are capable of elastically storing an extreme amount of energy, which can cause the bullet to bounce off or be deflected".

Comment: This seems to be a comment on Adamant's answer rather than an answer to the question.

Comment: Here's the short answer - NO.

Comment: Here's how I know:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlwlKEeJ0vU

Comment: Bulletproof is merely a LEVEL OF PROTECTION.  Bulletproof doesn't mean  it will stop every and any bullet on the planet.  Carbon nanotubes are good for .44 magnum, maybe (MAYBE) .500 SW, but will not stop an anti-tank round - AT ALL (or even a little bit).

Comment: "It probably would not matter whether they were shot with a machine gun, a rifle, or any other kind of standard gun. The force simply wouldn't be enough to penetrate their skin. One would need a purpose-built weapon to have any chance."  I have a question.  What is a "standard gun?"  How does a standard gun differ from a rifle?